# Using React.memo and useCallback to prevent functions from causing re-renders

Tags: reactjs, usecallback

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Ls48dd-vJE) demonstrating react's 'useCallback' hook along with React.memo to prevent a function being render unnecessarily. To prove the concept we use useRef to console the number of renders. This worked with the function alone but i added a function to randomize the button background color and I can't seem to no prevent the rendering of both functions.

```
    import React,{useState, useCallback, useRef} from 'react';
import './App.css';

const randomColor = () => `rgb(${Math.random()*255},${Math.random()*255},${Math.random()*255}`

const Button = React.memo(({increment, bgColor}) => {
const count = useRef(0)
console.log(count.current++)
return(
    <button onClick={increment} style={{backgroundColor: bgColor}}>increment</button>
  )
})

const App = React.memo(() => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const [color, setColor] = useState(`rgb(${Math.random()*255},${Math.random()*255},${Math.random()*255}`)



  const increment = useCallback(() => {  
    setCount(previousCount => previousCount + 1)
    setColor(randomColor)
  },[setCount,setColor])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h2>{count}</h2>
        <Button increment={increment} bgColor={color}>increment</Button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
})

export default App;

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    import React,{useState, useCallback, useRef} from 'react';
    import './App.css';

    const randomColor = () => `rgb(${Math.random()*255},${Math.random()*255},${Math.random()*255}`

    const Button = React.memo(({increment, bgColor}) => {
    const count = useRef(0)
    console.log(count.current++)
    return(
        <button onClick={increment} style={{backgroundColor: bgColor}}>increment</button>
      )
    })

    const App = React.memo(() => {
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
      const [color, setColor] = useState(`rgb(${Math.random()*255},${Math.random()*255},${Math.random()*255}`)



      const increment = useCallback(() => {  
        setCount(previousCount => previousCount + 1)
        setColor(randomColor)
      },[setCount,setColor])

      return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <h2>{count}</h2>
            <Button increment={increment} bgColor={color}>increment</Button>
          </header>
        </div>
      );
    })

    export default App;
```

Comment: can you post the useRandomColor source code?

Comment: Sorry just added it to the codebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It the example in the video you mentioned, the Button component does not change, because the props stay the same all the time. In your example, the `increment` stays the same, but the problem is that the `bgColor` changes with each click.

That means, that if you rendered only the main component and not the Button component, the background would have to be the same, but because it receives different background color each time, it would not make sense.

React will always re-render the component if the props change (if you don't implement custom shouldUpdate lifecycle method).

Comment: It makes sense now you explain it. Of course, the component re-renders it has to, to make the color change. Thanks for your time